With AgGrid using agRichSelectCellEditor, allowTyping is set to true, search is not possible when the dropdown option is the [object,object] data type
When I use AgGrid in react, I have a little problem editing the agRichSelectCellEditor function of a cell. When the drop-down item is not the array string [string,string] in the official example, but the array object [object,object], Search cannot be used, is there any other api to support this?
This is an example of the official website, it is normal to work, and this is what I expect to achieve：

Here are the problems I encountered：
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    {
      headerName: "Allow Typing (MatchAny)",
      field: "color",
      cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: [{ label: "SpringGreen", value:1},
                 { label: "Tan", value:2},
                 { label: "SteelBlue" ,value:3} ],
        cellRenderer: (params) => {
          return <div>{params?.value?.label}</div>;
        },
        searchType: "matchAny",
        allowTyping: true,
        filterList: true,
        highlightMatch: true,
        valueListMaxHeight: 220,
      },
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        return params.newValue?.label 
      },
    },
  ]);

This should be a common question about the options data type when array objects. I tried to solve it through the api given by the official, but I couldn't succeed. Maybe I didn't understand something, and I hope someone can help me.
